# Installing WHMCS - Access Violation

Tags: php, sql, whmcs

I am trying to install WHMCS and am running into a problem each time I run the installer. There is a problem with the timestamp option being used in the tblclient table and I am not sure how to go about fixing this.

This is the error I am receiving:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1067 Invalid default value for 'pwresetexpiry_temp'
>   (SQL: alter table `tblclients` add `pwresetexpiry_temp` timestamp not null)

Answer (score 2):

The WHMCS 7 documentation currently does not state which MySQL 5.7 sql_mode customizations need to be made. As WHMCS 7 was not written to support modern MySQL syntax, you must make customizations to MySQL to install and use WHMCS 7 with MySQL 5.7.

SSH in to your server as root and create this file:

**/etc/mysql/conf.d/disable_strict_mode.cnf**

Open the file and enter these two lines:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Restart MySQL with this command:

**sudo service mysql restart**

Hope this work for you! :) Cheers!!!